# Given the mean and standard deviation of a change, when can we expect to reach a threshold?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, mean

Suppose I am playing a game in which I start with 1000 points and my point total changes every turn. I lose when I reach 0 points. I know that after every turn I can expect that my point total will change by $\mu_1$ with standard deviation $\sigma_1$ (as per the normal distribution). When can I expect to lose the game? Or, perhaps what is the probability that I have lost after $t$ turns?

Now suppose I add a second player, Fred, who also starts with 1000 points. We play the game by alternating turns. During my turn I experience a point change, as before, and during Fred's turn he expects that his point total will change by $\mu_2$ with standard deviation $\sigma_2$. The game is done when one player's point total is no longer positive. What is the probability that I will win the game after $t$ turns (meaning the Fred loses)? When can I expect to win?

I realize that I can run a simulation to find empirical answers, but I would like to find more exact results. Thank you!

Comment: In continuous time, the distribution of times until loss would be an Inverse Gaussian or Wald distribution. If $\sigma_1$ is small compared to 1000, I'd expect this to be a reasonable approximation also for discrete time. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution